# How to do this code using Comparator?

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

Sorry, I don't work with Java since a long time. I have a class which sort int type, and I am trying to do this, but this does not compile:

```
MySort.sort(vectorOfInt, new Comparator() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
    return (int)o1 - (int)o2;
    }
    });
```

I would like to sort a vector of int using this method using the comparator to sort in ascending order.

```
public static  void sort(T[] a, Comparator c) {
        sort(a, 0, a.length, c);
}
```

Comment: can you explain crescent order?

Comment: crescent = ascending. Which is: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7...

Comment: cannot convert from object to int

Answer (score 3):

The sample code is rather incomplete, but to begin with you cannot cast Object to int. Use

```
return (Integer) o1 - (Integer) o2;
```

instead.

Comment: I updated the code. I don't understand much about the first parameter. Could you help me? Thanks.

Comment: @Seva, the first parameter T[] a is an array of the generic type T, i.e. the class is defined as MySort<T>.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a [typed Comparator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) and you won't need to cast the arguments.

```
MySort.sort(vectorOfInt, new Comparator<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
      return o1 - o2;
    }
    });
```

**EDIT:**
First off, please don't call an array a vector. [`Vector`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html) is a java class and people will assume that is what you are using when you name the variable `vectorOfInt`.

The compiler error you are getting is because the compiler doesn't know that your `Comparator` is operating on `Integer`s. Since all it sees is an `Object`, it doesn't know that o1 is actually an `Integer` and can be unboxed to be an `int`. By specifying the comparator type, you provide more information and the conversion can be made implicitly.

Comment: I updated the code. I don't understand much about the first parameter. Could you help me? Thanks.

Comment: thanks about the vector teach. But I still can't compile, because the sort method expects a T[] a parameter.

Comment: @Seva: Where is `T` defined? It isn't a generic method, so it has to be set by the containing class. What is the class signature that contains `sort()`?

Answer (score 1):

First off, don't use `Vector`, or `Hashtable` for that matter, they both are considered `deprecated` for all practical purposes. Use `List` or `Map` implementations.

Use a `List<Integer>` instead, it is the modern and correct way to manipulate a list of `Integer`s as objects.

```
final List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
... populate list ...
Collections.sort(list);
```

If you want to use a different `Comparator` then you can use:

```
Collections.sort(list, comparator);
```

Since `Integer` implements `Comparable`, this will by default sort the `List<Integer>` in ascending order. [Integer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) for the details.

This is the correct, idiomatic way of sorting `List` and `Collection` classes in modern Java. Anything else shows you don't understand the language and what it provides.

Comment: thanks, but in my case, I already have a sorting class. I updated the code.

Comment: you are doing it wrong then, you should never re-implement code that is already in the standard library.

Comment: @Jarrod, I'm not sure what you were trying to achieve, but your backticks near "List or Map" are producing formatting weirdness.

Comment: this code is a sorting algorithm which is not currently implemented in the Java 6. It will be implemented in Java 7.

Comment: If you are using a `Comparator` it is already in Java 6. `Comparator` and 'Comparable` has been in the language since the beginning. If you want to sort `Integer` then it is already built in. I don't see anything ground breaking in your code example that is new or enhanced over what `Integer` already does.

Comment: you missunderstood, the new thing that I'm talking about is the TimSort algorithm. The currently is a tuned quick sort or a tuned merge sort.